# Would a native of a future state be a natural born citizen?

Tags: united-states, president, citizenship

Let's imagine a 51st state is accepted into the United States (not necessarily Puerto Rico). Would someone who was born in that state, before it joins the US, be considered a natural-born citizen? What if that person was already a naturalized citizen of the US before the state is accepted?

Comment: None of the early presidents were born in states that were part of the USA, as the country didn't exist at the time. So I'd argue that the answer is yes.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: No, early presidents weren't natural-born citizens. The Constitution specifically allows people who were citizens at the time of the adoption of the Constitution to be president.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The U.S. Constitution uses but does not define the phrase *"natural born citizen"*.
Historically, there were explicit rulings regarding persons who were born on a territory prior to it became an U.S. state.
We don't know the future, but we can safely assume that for future 51st state, there will be similar rulings.

---

United States Code, Title 8, Sections 1404 and 1405 (markup is mine):

- [8 U.S. Code § 1404](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1404) — Persons born in Alaska on or after March 30, 1867:

  > A person born in Alaska on or after March 30, 1867, except a noncitizen Indian, **is a citizen of the United States at birth**. A noncitizen Indian born in Alaska on or after March 30, 1867, and prior to June 2, 1924, is declared to be **a citizen of the United States** as of June 2, 1924. An Indian born in Alaska on or after June 2, 1924, **is a citizen of the United States at birth**.
- [8 U.S. Code § 1405](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1405) —  Persons born in Hawaii:

  > A person born in Hawaii on or after August 12, 1898, and before April 30, 1900, is declared to be **a citizen of the United States** as of April 30, 1900. A person born in Hawaii on or after April 30, 1900, is **a citizen of the United States at birth**. A person who was a citizen of the Republic of Hawaii on August 12, 1898, is declared to be **a citizen of the United States** as of April 30, 1900.

---

Since this question is also tagged [president](/questions/tagged/president), I suppose that the OP's concern is whether or not persons who were born on a **territory** before it (the territory) became an U.S. **state** can become the U.S. President.

The answer is **yes**.
[Barry Goldwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Goldwater) was born in Arizona (1909) before it became a US State (1912).
He was Rep. nominee for President in the 1964 election.
His eligibility was challenged in the court.
The Supreme Court [made the ruling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-born-citizen_clause#Barry_Goldwater) that he is eligible for presidency.
The above Wikipedia link contains a good summary on this matter.

Comment: great answer! I wonder what the case would be with people who were naturalized US citizens at the time of joining the US. For example: imagine Austria joined the US ... would Schwarzenegger be elegible?

Comment: Goldwater was born in an incorporated territory, so he was a US citizen from birth. However, it is still possible for someone to have been born in a territory before it became a US territory, or after it became a US territory but before Congress extended birthright citizenship to it (all current US territories that are inhabited are unincorporated; Congress has extended birthright citizenship to some but not all of them, and even for the ones it extended birthright citizenship to, that often happened a while after it became a US territory). Such a person may not have been a US citizen at birth

Comment: @user102008 your point is supported by the fact that 8 USC Part I, which contains the sections cited here, is called "Nationality at Birth and Collective Naturalization."  This implies that (e.g.) the distinction made in section 1405 between "a citizen of the US at birth" and "a citizen of the US as of..." means that the latter are collectively naturalized, and therefore not natural-born citizens. (I've therefore downvoted this answer because the presidential eligibility analysis seems to be incorrect.)

Comment: Further, the target of the "made the ruling" link says nothing about the Supreme Court having ruled on the question of Goldwater's eligibility, nor have I found evidence elsewhere that it did so.